# Change background-color for each row using a color list Vue.js

Tags: css, variables, foreach, row, background-color

I'm currently listing some colors. Each row has two spans, one with the color Id and  the other is going to show a sample of the color.

```
   /* HTML */ 

     <ul>
         <li v-for="(ColorsList, index) in Colors" :key='index'>
            <span>{{ColorsList.COLOR_ID}}</span>
            <span class="test">{{ColorList.COLOR_HEX}}"></span>
         </li>
    </ul>


/* CSS */
.test {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: auto auto;
 background-color:  var(--COLORHEX);
}
```

I need to use the hex to paint the background-color of the span, one approach I've found is to use a variable in css. But this changes all the spans in the list when each row should have a unique color.
Any kind of help is much appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the same class for all `<span class="test">` elements, and that leads to the same styles for all spans.

Actually in your case, it should be fairly acceptable to use [inline styles](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-Inline-Styles) without the complexity of variables in css. Consider changing it to:

```
    <ul>
         <li v-for="(ColorsList, index) in Colors" :key='index'>
            <span>{{ColorsList.COLOR_ID}}</span>
            <span class="test"
             v-bind:style="{ backgroundColor: ColorList.COLOR_HEX }" // note this inline style binding
             >{{ColorList.COLOR_HEX}}"></span>
         </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: That helped me a lot... Thank you!